# Calculator with human readable notation, when it fits

Tags: lubuntu, calculator

I am using Galculator 2.1.4, a scientific calculator that came with Lubuntu (with LXQt desktop).
Galculator shows small numbers in decimal scientific notation (1e-05) which I don't like. For numbers bigger than one millionth I prefer 0.000001 and there is plenty of space in the interface to show it like that.
I can't find a setting for that in galculator. Is that possible at all or does anyone know another calculator with scientific functions and human readable notation.
Setting a thousand separator in galculator does not help.

Comment: You mention Lubuntu, but not what release. If you look at the manifest of Lubuntu 22.04 (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-amd64.manifest) you'll notice [`gcalculator`  is not there as its a GTK calculator](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/galculator), but `kcalc` does which is Qt5 just like the LXQt desktop (`kcalc 4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1` on *jammy*).  Please check your facts as the mention a calculator that doesn't come with Lubuntu, you've not said what release - are you using Lubuntu?

Comment: @guiverc, Not relevant for the question, but: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. If Galculator was not pre installed then I have no idea which one was. It was the only calculator on the system before I installed another one today.

Comment: @Quasímodo, thank you. I like Qalculator. It has a lot of settings, it took me a while before I found out how te set angle to degrees.

Comment: Correction: Kcalc is on the system but not in the menu. I can start it from within a terminal.

Comment: `kcalc` is found in the Accessories menu on a default install of Lubuntu 18.10 or higher, being the Qt5 calculator the Lubuntu team uses on the LXQt desktop. It's found in the Lubuntu manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/2/2.4/2.4.3/Kcalc.html as you clearly say Lubuntu which uses LXQt & thus Qt5 apps are included by default as they're *light* on that environment (GTK is only used if there are no *lighter* alternatives as they cannot share libs/tk with the desktop itself).  Your question details contradict.

Comment: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/focal/release/lubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.manifest will show what is included on a Lubuntu 20.04.5 install, ie. `kcalc 4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1` being the version that works best with the Qt5 libraries/toolkit installed in *focal*.   (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/lubuntu.focal/desktop being the *focal* seed file used to create the 20.04 ISOs)

Comment: It is installed by default, I believe you :-) And it should be in the accessories menu, but it is not. I don't know why and I have already removed kcalc from my system because qalculator is the winner.